# Which diff eq is used in electronic engineering?

Tags: differential

Its a projectthat our teacher gave us . To find which diff eq is used in this field .please help me.
(By diff eq i mean the diff eq like legendre or riccati that are famous and known by a special name )

Comment: you are not showing any effort to answer the question yourself. you are also too lazy to type the words `differential equations`.  why should anyone here do your school work for you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework assignment with **zero** effort shown by you to find an answer. We're not going to do **your** work for you.

Comment: *please help me* Uhm,... **Nope!!!**

Comment: Just an advice: if you want to type faster, omitting the emojis should be prioritized over writing incomplete words and spacing/capitalizing randomly.

Comment: @dim, OP's first language may well not be English. Doesn't stop theirs being a useless post but it may explain it :-)

Comment: @TonyM To be honest, no, it doesn't explain incomplete words, and the presence of useless emojis. I could understand the presence of some mistakes (I make some myself), but whatever language OP speaks natively, the way this post was written shows literally no efforts. And it made my eyes bleed.

Comment: You may find this a useful reference : http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap19/19_7.pdf

Comment: Research it yourself.... Thats how you should learn.....

Comment: Im sorry . Im just not good in English. But i know what is differential equation and also know that i have to do it myself.i've learned the RC and RL circuits and 1st and 2nd order of differential equations.but i wanted to know which one of the equations those are famous are used.in the university.i thought here i would find someone who is educated in this field .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your only components are

- resistors (V-I-relationship: \$v=Ri\$),
- capacitors (V-I-relationship: \$v=\frac{1}{C}\int{i})dt\$ and
- inductors (V-I-relationship: \$v=-L\frac{di}{dt}\$) and of course
- voltage and/or current sources (\$v(t)\$, \$i(t)\$)

your circuit (i.e. all currents and voltages vs. time) can be described by a
**system of max. 2nd order linear ordinary diffential equations with constant coefficients**.

If you allow also active components (e.g. OpAmps) you can build an analog computer for any ordinary differential equation you can imagine.